# Trabalhando com data: printar todas as datas em um determinado intervalo

Tags: java, data

Estou com dificuldades numa implementação simples. Preciso receber a quantidade de dias, tirando os sábados e domingos, a partir de um determinado intervalo de datas. Tentei usar Calendar, pois posso setar o dia(data), mês e ano e usar o `calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)` que me retornar o dia da semana em inteiro.

```
for (int i = firstYear; i <= currentYear; i++) {
    for (int j = firstMonth; j <= currentMonth; j++) {
        for (int d = firstDay; d <= currentDay; d++) {
            calendar.clear();
            calendar.set(i, j-1, d); // LEMRAR QUE O MÊS COMEÇA COM 0 E NÃO COM 1
            if((calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SUNDAY && calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SATURDAY)){
                count++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

O mais perto que cheguei foi o código acima, mas quando, por exemplo, o mês iniciais é menor mas o dia não, ele não faz o que deveria fazer.

Comment: Não entendi a frase: "o mês iniciais é menor mas o dia não". Poderia explicar melhor?

Answer (score 1):

O problema se encontra aqui

`for (int d = firstday; d <= currentDay; d++)`

No caso vc deve fazer ele rodar ate o ultimo dia do mês e dentro fazer um if que verifique se o dia que se quer corresponde ao mês e fazer um `break`.

```
for (int d = firsDay; d <= lastDayMonth; d++)
{
    if ( currentYear == i && currentMonth == j && currentDay == d)
        break;
}
```

No caso foi o que consegui entender que você deseja parar no dia, mês e ano estipulado, e neste caso lastDayMonth deve ser configurado para pegar o ultimo dia de cada mês no caso logo antes de se iniciar este ultimo for.

Detalhe que esqueci de colocar anteriormente, os dias sempre devem começar a partir de 1 se você deseja imprimir todos os dias no intervalo, quando vc colocar firstday você complica o sistema, já que todos os dias começam a partir do dia 1.

Segundo detalhe você pode começar o dia a a partir do dia 5 mas depois para o próximo mês você deve zerar e colocar para dia 1.

Também e importante lembrar que quando se passa 1 ano você deve zerar o contador dos meses e retornar a 1, isto é sempre que month > 12 = 1 ai você consegue nesta ideia ficar alterando o mês sem erros.

Espero que seja esta sua duvida.

Att.
Thiago Prado